# String substitution when strings are externalized to a separate file

Tags: javascript, typescript, string-substitution

I have extracted all strings from my code and put them into a file called `constants.ts` ..

```
export class Constants {
  public static API_URL = '/api/';
  public static CREATE_CHILD_API_URL = Constants.API_URL + '%s' + '/create-child';
}
```

I'm able to substitute a value into the string using `console.log`:

```
import { Constants } from '../common/constants';
console.log(Constants.CREATE_CHILD_API_URL, 'dummyId');
```

Produces this in console: `/api/dummyId/create-child` which is the goal.

How can I do the same but store the result in a variable for later use?

Is there something I can use that is native and runs on modern browsers without having to pull in a lib?

`Template literals` don't seem to suite the use case since the variable will not be defined in my constants file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will eventually make a mistake with this approach. I would rather recommend to use functions with certain parameters which will generate strings you need by executing strings interpolation inside:

```ts
export class Urls {
  public static API_URL = '/api/';
  public static CREATE_CHILD_API_URL =
      (id: string) => `${Urls.API_URL}${id}/create-child`;
}
```

Later you will be able to use it like this:

```ts
import { Urls } from '../common/urls';
const forLaterUse = Urls.CREATE_CHILD_API_URL('dummyId');
console.log(forLaterUse);
```